# New File in Php

Tags: php, file

How do you create a new file in php. I am trying to use the fopen function. But as far as I can tell that only works if the file already exists. I am interesting in

1. Opening a file if it exists
2. If it does not exist create a new text file
3. Read and writing to the file.

Comment: Yes you need to give another param called `mode`. Just scroll down a bit below for the `modes` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fopen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) will open a non existing file if you pass it a mode flag:

```
fopen("myfile.txt", "w"); //places the pointer at 0 and overwrites any existing data or creates new
fopen("myfile.txt", "w+"); //opens for writing and reading
```

the [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) function will dump data into a file:

```
$data = "my data block";
$myFile = "myFile.txt";
file_put_contents($myFile, $data);
```

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents): the possible arguments for `file_put_contents()` are:

> `filename` Path to the file where to write the data.
>
> `data` The data to write. Can be either a string, an array or a stream resource. If data
> is a stream resource, the remaining buffer of that stream will be
> copied to the specified file. This is similar with using
> stream_copy_to_stream(). You can also specify the data parameter as a
> single dimension array. This is equivalent to
> file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $array)).

> `flags` The value of
> flags can be any combination of the following flags, joined with the
> binary OR (|) operator.

To check if a file exists use the [`file_exists()`](https://www.php.net/function.file-exists) function and [`fopen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) or  [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if you want to suck  the existing  data into a variable:

```
if(file_exists($myFile)) 
{
     fopen($myFile); 
     //do something
} else {
     //use file_put_contents or fopen to dump file    
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. I totally already knew about the file_put_contents() I must have just had a brain fart. Sorry for the simple question. Thanks